# Demora na inicialização da aplicação

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, typescript

Criei uma aplicação multiplataforma usando Ionic 2 + Angular 2 de acordo com a *Get started* da [documentação do Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/). O comando básico para criar um projeto com menu lateral é desta forma abaixo:

```
$ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

Tem alguma coisa que está incomodando muito que é a inicialização do aplicativo, na plataforma Android, que hoje está demorando em torno de 14(mega, master, hiper, ultra) segundos (o Rubens Barrichello daria 5 voltas no Circuito de Mônaco).

Pesquisei um pouco e encontrei algo falando que acontece isso quando o *app* está em modo *debug*, porém gerei uma versão de *release* e continua lento na inicialização. Testei no IOS e a velocidade de carregamento é muito rapida, que seria o normal acontecer. Alguém já deparou com isso? Existe alguma configuração que precisa ser realizada para resolver o problema?

Comment: Já tentou colocar no main.ts o seguinte código? `enableProdMode();`

Comment: @DiegoAugusto mas qual seria a justificativa? Vou tentar ver aqui.

Comment: Ele desabilita o 'hotdeploy', ou seja não ficará escutando as mudanças no código e recarregando-as

Comment: Outra dúvida, vc não fez nenhuma alteração ainda no template que foi baixado? Ou está fazendo seu aplicativo em cima dele?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto já tentei sim, mas sem sucesso! Continua lento.  Estou fazendo em cima do aplicativo que foi gerado a partir do starter.

Comment: Beleza, então vc já tem bastante modulos certo? Está carregando eles tudo no app.module.ts?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto sim, estou carregando tudo no app.moodule.ts. hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para melhorar o desempenho do seu aplicativo você pode utilizar uma *técnica secreta milenar* chamada `LazyLoading` (Carga preguiçosa). No [ionic a aplicação deste modelo](https://blog.paulhalliday.io/2017/06/23/ionic-3-lazy-loading-components/) consiste em carregar os módulos necessários pra cada página no momento do carregamento da mesma, evitando carregar todos os módulos, providers, etc no inicio do app.

Vamos supor que você tem um `component/page` chamada `home`, eu teria a seguinte estrutura de arquivos:

```
home.ts
home.scss
home.html
```

Para implementar o lazy é necessário a criação de mais um arquivo, que é o arquivo que vai importar o que você precisar.

```
home.module.ts
```

Para utilizar o `lazy` também é necessário fazer alguns ajustes, no seu arquivo `home.ts` você precisar utilizar o decorator `@IonicPage()`. Exemplo:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class Home {}
```

Já no seu arquivo home.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Home } from './home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Home,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(Home),
  ],
  exports: [
    Home
  ]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

Quando você chamar sua página `Home`, consecutivamente o `HomeModule` será chamado e o mesmo irá carregar seus componentes.

Uma coisa importante, você não precisa mais utilizar o component importado para fazer o roteamento, você só precisar passar a string com o nome do mesmo, exemplo: `this.nav.push('Home');`

Observação, você pode importar seus providers tbm no home.module.ts, é só adicionar o atributo `providers: []` na estrutura do `NgModule`

Comment: Então você já passou por isso é resolveu o problema assim?! Faz muito sentido o que você está dizendo. Vou fazer um teste e te falo. Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Sim, consegui reduzir o tempo de inicialização do app consideravelmente.

Comment: Cara, demorei pra ajustar tudo mas foi. Porém não melhorou tanto assim. Achei que aquela tela branca de início praticamente iria sumir. huehuhe... mas ainda estou perdendo um pouco de performance. Você teria outra dica ?!

Comment: Já tentou compilar pra produção?  ionic cordova run android --prod --release

Comment: Eu fiz isso antes mesmo de fazer a alteração que vc sugeriu. Ai tinha diminuido um pouco o tempo. Agora depois ainda não tentei compilar como prod. Vou fazer isso e te aviso.,

Comment: Beleza! Tente ver se melhora

Comment: Vou validar sua resposta, mas pra mim ainda deve haver mais alguma coisa. Querendo ou não a estratégia do LazyLoading funciona, mas meu caso ainda queria mais um pouco de performance. Tem alguma coisa errada no meu código talvez. Vlw. Se suspeitar de alguma coisa, me avise. hehe